# Upload Files to Sharepoint Library through WS with PHP (NTLM & ThyBag)

Tags: php, web-services, sharepoint

I use the Lists-WS from Sharepoint to retrieve information about DocumentLibraries and the files in these Libraries. Now I want to upload new files. How do I implement uploads with PHP? Till now I use Thybag SharePointAPI to get information ([Link](https://github.com/thybag/PHP-SharePoint-Lists-API)).

(the SharepointServer uses NTLM-Authentication)

THX in advance!!

UPDATE:

I want to call the Copy.asmx WS from sharepoint. To do so, I use the following lines:

```
    $sourceurl = 'http://null';

    $params = '
        <CopyIntoItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
            <SourceUrl>'.$sourceurl.'</SourceUrl>
            <DestinationUrls>' . $destinationURLs . '</DestinationUrls>
            <Stream>' . $stream . '</Stream>
        </CopyIntoItems>
            ';

    $xmlvar = new \SoapVar($params, XSD_ANYXML);
    // Attempt to run operation
    try {
        $result = $this->soapClient->CopyIntoItems($xmlvar)->CopyIntoItemsResponse->CopyIntoItemsResult;
    } catch (\SoapFault $fault) {
       $this->onError($fault);
    }
```

But I dont even get any response ($result == NULL).....

Answer (score -1):

You can use [SPServices' CopyIntoItems](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Copy) method. You can find a detailed conversation [here](http://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/83778) containing the details on using the CopyIntoItems service to upload a document.